# NGINX proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/ Not Found

Tags: javascript, nginx, web, quasar

I run my webapp on NGINX with the following configuration:

```
# Based on https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/#nginx-conf
# user              www www;  ## Default: nobody

worker_processes  auto;
error_log         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log";
pid               "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/nginx.pid";

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format    main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
  '"$request" $status  $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log    "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log";
  add_header    X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

  client_body_temp_path  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
  proxy_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
  fastcgi_temp_path      "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
  scgi_temp_path         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
  uwsgi_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;

  sendfile           on;
  tcp_nopush         on;
  tcp_nodelay        off;
  gzip               on;
  gzip_http_version  1.0;
  gzip_comp_level    2;
  gzip_proxied       any;
  gzip_types         text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  ssl_protocols      TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  client_max_body_size 80M;
  server_tokens off;
  include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/*.conf";

  # HTTP Server
  server {
    # port to listen on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT
    listen  8080;

    location /api/* {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9999;

    }

    location /status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log   off;
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny all;
    }
  }
}
```

and the way that I do the call:

```
methods: {
  load_user(event) {

    console.log(this.$kc)

    const config = {
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$kc.token}`}
    };

    this.$axios.get('/api/hello/sali', config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("errro")
      })
  },
```

Then it shows the following message:

[image]

However, it should return:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm almost sure this isn't the answer but it looks like you want to get a `json`. however you `Content-Type:` says `text/html`. Instead of `application/json`

Comment: Yes exactly, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Not is recomendly that you put your **web server** inside of nginx configuration, you have that create a file inside of folder **sites-enabled**. And with the main problem:

In you `javascript` code you `httpRequest` is pointing to `PORT` **8090** but the `port` that is in nginx-config is **8080**

[image]

The real problem is in your **javascript code** try with port **9999** or **8080**

Answer (score 0):

You're listening on port 8080, not 8090, have you tried that?

```
localhost:8080
```